# NSURLSession - Ignore SSL certificate warning

Tags: ios, security, ssl, https, nsurlsession

I am working on an iOS 8+ App that should allow the users to communicate with a **WebService on their own servers**. Of course using a HTTPS connection would best practice to do this but in reality there will be a lot of users who do not have a (trusted) SSL certificate on their server.

I would like to allow the users to decide on their own whether they want to use plain HTTP or HTTPS. **Additionally HTTPS should work, even if the server has now valid SSL certificate.** Since the certificate "only" ensures the identity of the server but has no effect on the encryption of the connection it self, untrustes HTTPS sill has its advantages over plain HTTP:

- I know that certificates have been invented for a good reason
- I know about the risks of MITM attacks
- I agree that using a valid SSL cert would be the best option
- I still believe, that using HTTPS without a cert should be an option for the users.

So, how to do this?

First I worked with `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` but since this does not allow any control about the cert checking process (and because it is deprecated in iOS 9) I switched to NSURLSession.

I followed [Apples docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECNSURLSESSION) to trust my server but had no success:

```
- (id)init {
    ...
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    ...
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {    
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
    } else {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
    }
}

- (void)sendRequest:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // ERROR
            --> Log error
        } else {
            // SUCCESS
        }
    }] resume];
}

- (void)test {
    // HTTP works fine
    [self sendRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.test.page.xy"]];

    // Error with HTTPS
    [self sendRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my.test.page.xy"]];

    // Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
    // Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
    // UserInfo={
    //     _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824,
    //     NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
    //     NSUnderlyingError= {
    //         Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
    //         Code=-1200
    //         UserInfo={
    //             _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
    //             _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824,
    //             _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
    //             _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824
    //         }
    //     },
    //     NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.,
    //     NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://my.test.page.xy,
    //     NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://my.test.page.xy,
    //     _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3
    // }
 }
```

Whether I handle `URLSession:session task:didReceiveChallenge:challenge completionHandler:` or not makes no difference. The error is the same.

So, any idea how to use HTTPS on servers without a certificate? According to the [Apples docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECNSURLSESSION) this should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, because in today's world security is irrelevant, right? Doing something like this just makes the problem worse, is that a good idea? Attackers just look for a weak point, they do not care how secure other parts are. And there are always excuses for poor security.

Comment: This is your opinion and has nothing to do with the question. If someone has a server but no SSL certificate he would be forced to use plain HTTP. NO authentication and NO integrity/encryption. How exactly does this make thinks worse compared to HTTPS without a cert (NO authentication but still encryption)? Many NAS boxes can be used with HTTPS but have no (trusted) certificate. Why shouldn't it be possible to use HTTPS in these cases?

Comment: True, my opinion is that security should be a requirement and if present should be real. If there is no cert https is not possible, it is the public key from the cert that is used to encrypt the symmetric encryption key. If there is no trusted cert and no pinning there is only the appearance of security and that is worse than no security, that is the user trusts something that shouldn't be trusted. Attacks these days are quite sophisticated yet rather easily applied by an attacker.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know the certificate is used for authentication only (thus preventing MITM attacks) while the encryption key is generated and exchanged using Diffie-Hellman. Thus encryption will work even if no certificate is available.

Comment: The use of ECDHE (Diffie-Hellman) is part of "Perfect Forward Secrecy" and not all https installations use that. SSL and TLS lower than 1.2 are prevalent as is the use of poor cryptographic fallback algorithms such as RC4. Certificates do not protect against MITM attacks unless the certificate is pinned. Pining verifies that the certificate is indeed the correct certificate. Traffic sniffers such as Charles Proxy display https content by being a MITM, they add their certificate to the OS. See [SSL PROXYING](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/).

Comment: did you solve this problem ? @AndreiHerford

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to actually evaluate the trust object once (though the actual result of that evaluation is ignored).

With that said, *please* check to make sure it is actually *your* cert before you accept it.  See [Overriding SSL Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) for examples of how to do this.